# Qt for android : am getting device is offline even though for eclipse it appears online

Tags: android, qt

Am trying to run Qt sample on my android device Samsung S4, but the problem it always shows its offline even though when I try on eclipse it is online.

I have tried to kill the adb server also to restart the phone and to turn on and off the debugging on my phone but not work !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the issues by downloading Samsung Galaxy S4 USB Drivers. it fixes everything.

link for the download : http://downloadcenter.samsung.com/content/SW/201212/20121213040816385/Samsung_USB_Driver_for_Mobile_Phones_v1.5.14.0.exe